# ADD STATUS COLUMN FROM SELECT FULL OUTER JOIN to identify that matched and unmatched

Tags: sql, oracle

Using FULL OUTER JOIN, I need an extra column to identify the matched data, unmatched data from table1, and unmatched data from table2. Having trouble identifying as the table construction doesn't have a primary key (I can't change the table structure of the 2 tables).

```
SELECT 
    a.column1,
    a.column2, 
    a.column3,
    a.column4, 
    a.column5,
--EXTRA COLUMN(STATUS) to identify the MATCHED(M), UNMATCHED FROM table1(UT1), UNMATCHED FROM table2(UT2)
FROM 
table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN
table2 b ON
a.column1 = b.column1 AND
a.column2 = b.column2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values from the table will be null when there is no match.

```
SELECT 
    a.column1,
    a.column2, 
    a.column3,
    a.column4, 
    a.column5,
CASE 
    WHEN b.column1 IS null THEN 'UT1'
    WHEN a.column1 IS null THEN 'UT2'
    ELSE 'M'
END as STATUS
FROM 
table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN
table2 b ON
a.column1 = b.column1 AND
a.column2 = b.column2;
```